# How to focus window after show?

Tags: windows, wxwidgets

I have window with global shortcut registered:

```
RegisterHotKey(SHOWHIDE_HOTKEY, wxMOD_CONTROL, VK_OEM_3);
```

with it's handle looking like this:

```
if (IsShown()) {
    Hide();
} else {
    Show();
    SetFocus();
}
```

The hiding/showing of the window works fine, the focus part doesn't. Any ideas how can I achieve it?

Comment: I don't see any relationship between registering a hot key and setting focus. Normally `SetFocus()` should work, of course, if it doesn't you would need to make a small example showing it, otherwise it's really hard to say what goes wrong.

Comment: SetFocus() doesn't cut it, surely you'll want to window to be on top.  That requires SetForegroundWindow() instead, not so sure that wxWidgets wraps that.

Comment: "surely you'll want to window to be on top" that's taken care of by ALWAYS_ON_TOP flag or what's it called.

Comment: @HansPassant ok, I take it back, SetForegroundWindow actually solves my issue with focus! can you post it as answer?

Comment: Just post the answer yourself, you know wxWidgets better than I do.